# Database scalability: Which is more important, size of table or number of queries?

Tags: sql, database-design, scalability, scaling

I'll take a simplified StackOverflow system as an example.

Although limiting some features, it would be possibly to hold Questions and Answers in the same table:

```
(Django-esque pseudo-code)

QA table:
    parent = ForeignKey(self)
    category = ForeignKey(Category)
    title = CharField()
    description = TextField()
```

Then, to get the Questions and Answers for Question with ID 1, an SQL SELECT would be done for `id==1` or `parent==1`. The downfall would be that the `tags` and `title` fields aren't used by Answers

The alternative of course would be two tables:

```
Questions:
    category = ForeignKey(Category)
    title = CharField()
    description = TextField()

Answers:
    parent = ForeignKey(Questions)
    description = TextField()
```

Which would require two queries to get the Questions and Answers.

Instinct says the former is a horrible idea but I'm not sure why.

Which is faster and more scalable?

Comment: There is a lot more to scalability than either of these factors. Load on server, number of concurrent client, indexing strategy, caching strategy and many more factors go into it. This question is not really answerable.

Comment: The answer in this case is most likely going to be "it depends on which database + version + indexes you are using (+ how much memory is available to your database) - so profile and find out".  Both structures only require a single query to pull questions and answers, and both select statements *can* be done with a join.

Comment: "The downfall would be that the tags and title fields aren't used by Answers" -- Yes. **So don't do that.** Start with a "good" normalized database design. The problems will come, as will the solutions. Starting with a "good base" will reduce the number of problems that need to be dealt with and increase the chance that the solutions can focus entirely on the real problem and not something needlessly introduced. (The size of the table is only terribly relevant if indexes' *can't* "select out" the subset of rows actually required for query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions directly, your instinct is correct.  Mixing entities (Questions and Answers) together into one table is almost always a bad idea.  Logically they are 2 separate entities and physically they should be kept separate.

Your second solution is the correct one.  Using indexes and foreign keys to link the 2 tables via the question id would allow you to select all the answers for any of the questions.  This would be faster and would scale better in addition to being more understandable to anyone who had to work with the structure in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one good answer here.  The best answer, in my humble opinion, is that it depends.  For example, if you put questions and answers in two separate tables, you limit yourself to that model.  You cannot, for example, have a sub-answer or sub-question in some sort of hierarchy.  This may be fine but it may not necessarily suit your environment.

Personally, I try to look at the situation and the data.  If I have to store different data about a question compared to an answer (or if I have to use the same column for two different purposes), I instead create two tables.  If the data is the same and is going to always be the same, I store it in one table.

Beyond just this limited view of the database schema, however, is a much bigger picture that needs to be considered.  For example, what is best for your storage engine?  What is best for your hardware?  For backups?  For archiving?  Performance and scalability will depend on a number of factors.  This is a good place to start the discussion, but it is just the tip of the iceberg.